# Calling a function from string inside the same module in Python?

Tags: python, string, function

Lets say I have a function `bar` inside a module called `foo.py` . Somewhere inside foo.py, I want to be able to call bar() from the string "bar". How do I do that?

```
# filename: foo.py
import sys

def bar():
  print 'Hello, called bar()!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  funcname = 'bar'
  # Here I should be able to call bar() from funcname
```

I know that there exists some built-in function in python called 'getattr'. However, it requires 'module object' to be the first parameter. How to obtain the 'module object' of the current module?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`globals` is probably easier to understand.  It returns the current module's `__dict__`, so you could do:

```
func_I_want = globals()['bar']  #Get the function
func_I_want()    #call it
```

If you *really* want the module object, you can get it from `sys.modules` (but you usually don't need it):

```
import sys.modules
this_mod = sys.modules[__name__]
func = getattr(this_mod,'bar')
func()
```

Note that in general, you should ask yourself why you want to do this.  This will allow *any function* to be called via a string -- which is probably user input... This can have potentially bad side effects if you accidentally give users access to the wrong functions.

Answer (score 19):

Use a dictionary that keeps the mapping of functions you want to call:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  funcnames = {'bar': bar}
  funcnames['bar']()
```

Comment: I always appreciate an answer that solves the OP's _problem_ rather than her/his _question_. +1