# Make a function to call while the program is running

Tags: python

For example, I have a program that can add letters and remove letters from list. Here's the code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

do = input("Press 'a' to append and 'r' to remove: ")

if do == 'a':
    letter = input("Enter a letter to append: ")
    my_list.append(letter)
    print (my_list)

elif do == 'r':
    letter = input("Enter a letter to append: ")
    my_list.remove(letter)
    print (my_list)

else:
    print ("Something gone wrong...")
```

To remove a letter from list I have to tell the program what I'm going to do and then it asks me for a letter to remove. Is there any possible way to call my own function (just to make it easier to use the program) like this:

```
def removing(letter):
    my_list.remove(letter)
    print (my_list)
```

To use the function in console like this:

```
What are you going to do? removing(b)
```

Comment: If you are using `input()` rather than `raw_input()` it should do that anyway.  From the docs for `input()`, `input([prompt]) -> value   Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))`

Comment: You wish to inject your own code into a running program?   Yes it can be done but few programs would support it for security reasons.  It would be better to pass data via something like a pipe.

Comment: @zondo: you are assuming the OP is using Python 2, which might not be the case

Comment: @cdarke Ah, now I realize why I see this all over the place.  In that case ,@Andrew, you could do `eval(input("Enter a letter to append"))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Calling a function from string inside the same module in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12846054)

Comment: I don't want to inject my code into a running program. I just want to help a user to work with the program. So they don't waste their time on picking the 'next steps' just to perform an operation. It would be great if you can just type like **add n** or  **remove b**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a somewhat restructured suggestion. It asks the user to either input

append something

or

remove something

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

choices = {'remove': my_list.remove,
           'append': my_list.append}

print my_list
while True:
    try:
        choice, item = raw_input('append <x> OR remove <x>\n').split()
        choices[choice](item)
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        print('something went wrong...')
    print my_list
```

Demo:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
append <x> OR remove <x>
append z
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'z']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove d
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'z']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove y
something went wrong...
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'z']
```

This should give you an idea/get you started. The dictionary is easily extendable.

Comment: Yay! That's exactly what I needed! Thank you. P.S. works perfect with 2.7 but gives "unexpected eof while parsing" error on 3.5 when I use `eval(input('append <x> OR remove <x>\n')).split() `

Comment: @Andrew in Python3, change all `print foo` statements to `print(foo)` function calls and use `input` (without `eval`) instead of `raw_input`. Never use `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 3):

For fun, you could expand the answer from @timgeb to accept multiple arguments at once.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

choices = {'remove': my_list.remove,
           'append': my_list.append}

def call_choice(name, *args):
    for arg in args: 
        choices[name](arg)

print my_list
while True:
    try:
        input_string = raw_input('append <x> OR remove <x>\n')
        call_choice(*input_string.split())
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        print('something went wrong...')
    print my_list
```

Demo:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
append <x> OR remove <x>
append a b c d e f g
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove a b c
['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove a
['d', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove d
['e', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
append <x> OR remove <x>
remove e f b c d e f g
[]
```