# How can I concatenate 2 variables, to call another variable of that combination?

Tags: python, function, loops, user-defined-functions

I have a defined function that includes a counter to know how many times it has been used, and asks for a user input of either L, R or F.
I want it to then check the input and add it to the counter and call the function of that name.
eg:
user choose L
count is at 3
call function L3

here is what I have so far, but I get an error:

```
def getUserDirection():
    getUserDirection.counter = 0
    getUserDirection.counter += 1
    direction = str(input("Which direction do you wish to go? (L/F/R) "))
    direction = direction.upper()
    if direction not in ("L", "F", "R"):
        print("whats does {} mean? You were meant to type 'L', 'F' or 'R'! Try again..".format(direction))
        direction = getUserDirection()
    elif direction == "L":
        print(direction()+counter())
    elif direction == "F":
        print(direction()+counter())
    elif direction == "R":
        print(direction()+counter())
    return getUserDirection()
```

The other functions I want it to call are:

```
def L1():
    print("you go left and see...")
def F1():
    print("You continue forward and see...")
def R1():
    print("You go right and see...")
```

The idea is to loop through `getUserDirection()` and call a different function with each pass. There will be plenty of functions as it progresses eg L1, L2, L3... each having a different story and new choice of direction to make.

What am I doing wrong?

**FULL CODE**

```
#PLAYER DETAILS
first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
while True:
    middle = input("Do you have a middle name? (y/n) ")
    if middle.upper() not in ("Y", "N"):
        print("whats does {} mean? You were meant to type 'y' or 'n'! Try again.." .format(middle))
    elif middle.upper() == "Y":
        middle_name = input("What is it? ")
        break
    elif middle.upper() == "N":
        middle_name = None
        break
# is_middle_empty = bool(middle_name)
# print(is_middle_empty)
print("So your full name is {} {} {}? ".format(first_name, '' if middle_name is None else middle_name, last_name))
import time
time.sleep(1)
print("Hmmm..")
time.sleep(1)
just_first = str(input("Should I just call you {}? (y/n) ".format(first_name)))
if just_first.upper() == "Y":
   player = first_name
   print("Great, nice to meet you", player)
elif just_first.upper() != "Y":
   name = first_name, "" if middle_name is None else middle_name, last_name
   player = " ".join(name)
   print("Sorry about that, let's stick to {} then." .format(player))
print()

#DIRECTION FUNCTION
def getUserDirection():
    getUserDirection.counter = 0
    getUserDirection.counter += 1
    direction = str(input("Which direction do you wish to go? (L/F/R) "))
    direction = direction.upper()
    if direction not in ("L", "F", "R"):
        print("whats does {} mean? You were meant to type 'L', 'F' or 'R'! Try again..".format(direction))
        direction = getUserDirection()
    elif direction == "L":
        print(direction()+counter())
    elif direction == "F":
        print(direction()+counter())
    elif direction == "R":
        print(direction()+counter())
    return getUserDirection()



#STORY LINES
def start():
    print("You have arrived at ... To your left (L) is ..., ahead (F) is ... To your right (R) is ...")
def L1():
    print("you go left")
def F1():
    print("You continue forward")
def R1():
    print("You turn right")

#ADVENTURE-1
adventure = input("So do you fancy a quick adventure? (y/n) ")
if adventure.upper() == "Y":
    print("Great then lets set off...")
elif adventure.upper() == "N":
    print("Ah well, I guess we can't all be ubercool adventurers like me, fairwell {}, I hope we meet again some day." .format(player))

#ADVENTURE-2
time.sleep(1)
print(start())
print(getUserDirection())
```

**ERROR TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(getUserDirection())
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 43, in getUserDirection
    print(direction()+counter())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Done, also added full code so far, thanks quamrana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function from string inside the same module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846054/calling-a-function-from-string-inside-the-same-module-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to store your functions in a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)-

```py
def L1():
    print("you go left and see...")
def F1():
    print("You continue forward and see...")
def R1():
    print("You go right and see...")

# define more functions....

inp_to_func = {
    'L1': L1,
    'F1': F1,
    'R1': R1
     # define more key-value pairs....
}
```

Which you can then use like-

```py
func = inp_to_func.get(f'{direction}{counter()}')
if not func:
    # no function found for input
    # do error handling here
    pass
else:
    func()
```

This assumes `direction` is a string and `counter()` returns a number - and combining them in the shown order forms the key in the dictionary.

Edit: If you have a `counter` **variable** instead, and not a function - you'd have to do `f'{direction}{counter}'` of course. It just seemed from your code that `counter` is a function you have defined that returns a number.

Suppose `direction` is a string variable with the value of `'L'`, and `counter` is an `int` variable with the value of `1`.

`f'{direction}{counter}'` gives you `'L1'`

If `L1` is a key in the `inp_to_func` dictionary and its value is a function object, `inp_to_func.get('L1')` will return said function object.

The function object can now be treated like any other function, that is - it can be called using parens - `()`.

So, going **line by line**-

```py
func = inp_to_func.get(f'{direction}{counter}')
# ^ Gets the function object corresponding to the input, or `None`
if not func:
    # ^ func was `None` (as in, no key was found)
    # no function found for input
    # do error handling here
    pass
else:
    func()
    # ^ calls the function
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand this, so I'd define the functions as I already have, then add a matching key-value pair for each in `inp-to-func`  But then how and where would I use the second part of the code, that bits confused me!

Comment: @BennMoffat you'd use that where you need to call the function corresponding to the input. `.get` obtains the function given by the key constructed using `f'{direction}{counter}`. You can then call that function.

Comment: So I tried to call `print(func)` thinking it would print the result F1 etc, but I get and error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    func = inp_to_func.get(f'{direction()}{counter()}')
NameError: name 'direction' is not defined`

Comment: @BennMoffat Please consider going through [the basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html). The error means you do not have a variable named `direction` in the current scope. Also, if `direction` is supposed to be a string variable, why are you trying to call it like a function (`direction()`)? Also, printing a function object does not print its result - you need to **call** the function using `func()` which will return its result. [Relevant doc on fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I'll add an edit for further explanation of the fstring

Comment: Thank you Chase, that's very helpful, I'll do more reading and follow the tutorial, as you probably guessed this is my first attempt at python, your help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: @BennMoffat I've added a line by line explanation which will hopefully help a bit. If this post answers your question, consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: that makes so much more sense to me now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing the `globals` or by using `eval`.

```py
direction, counter = "L", 1
globals()[f"{direction}{counter}"]() # globals return a dictionary, where you can access the variable through this dictionary.
eval(f"{direction}{counter}()") # eval evaluates python expression, in this case, the function call
```

This is what you're looking for based on your question, although if I would do this... I would probably create a single function then pass the `direction` and `counter` arguments to it.

```py
def fun(direction, counter):
  if direction == "L":
    if counter == 1:
      # do something...
  elif direction == "R":
    # do something...

direction, counter = "L", 1

# then you'll call it like...
fun(direction, counter)
```

Comment: Not sure this would work as I need not only L1, L2, L3 etc. but also F1, F2 etc. and  R1, R2 etc. I'm not sure how to implement that!

Comment: @BennMoffat, just make more conditions like in the example, group your conditions like make another `elif direction == "F" and counter == 1`